# 2D deSitter conserved charges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, vector-fields, de-sitter-spacetime

For $1+1$-dimensional dS spacetime, the metric takes the form (in comoving coordinates) $$\mathrm{d}s^2=\left(\mathrm{d}x^0\right)^2-e^{2Hx^0}\left(\mathrm{d}x^1\right)^2.$$ I want to find the conserved charges associated with translation and boost transformations.

---

I know that this (maximally symmetric) spacetime posses 3 independent Killing vectors and I tried to solve the Killing equation, that looks like $$\partial_\mu K_\nu + \partial_\nu K_\mu - 2 \Gamma^\sigma_{\mu\nu}K_\sigma = 0.$$ The only non-vanishing Christoffel symbols are $$\Gamma^1_{01}=-H,\; \; \; \Gamma^0_{11}=-He^{2Hx^0},$$ so I get $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\partial_0 K_1 + \partial_1 K_0 + 2HK_1 =0\\ \\
\partial_1K_1 + He^{2Hx^0} K_0=0\\
\end{matrix}\right.$$ I don't know how to proceed: any hint?

Comment: Apply $\partial_1$ on the first equation: $\partial_0\partial_1 K_1 + \partial^2_1 K_0 +2 H \partial_1 K_1 =0$ and replace then $\partial_1 K_1$ by $-H e^{2Hx^0}$. You get a 2nd ODE for $K_0$ which can be solved easily. Then solve for $K_1$.

Comment: @FredericThomas, The equation for $K_0$ reads
$$\partial^2_1 K_0 -4He^{2Hx^0}K_0 =0.$$
Why should I treat it as an ODE, not as a PDE? However, if this were an ODE, it would be an harmonic oscillator: shall I really expect an "harmonic" Killing vector? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: So then the solution for $K_0$ is ($A$ and $B$ integration constants):  $K_0 = A sinh(gx) +B cosh(gx)$ with   $g =2 e^{Hx^0}\sqrt{H}$. And $\partial_1 K_0=Ag cosh(gx)+ Bg sinh(gx)$. Put the latter in the first eq. which turns out to be inhomogeneous ODE of first order, so easy to solve (or look it up in a textbook on mathematics for physicsts). Once found the solution, check that it fulfills the 2. eq. BTW the $K_0$ is not a harm. solution which would be $\sim \cos$ or $\sin$